# How to use an array as a closed list of strings in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I was wondering how can I use **a regular JavaScript array** as a list of possible strings for a typescript interface, so it would act like:

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: "x"|"y"|"z"
}
```

But I could not figure out how to map the values of `names` properly:

```
const names = [`x`, `y`, `z`] as const;

interface MyInteface {
    name: (typeof names)[string] // ERROR: Type 'readonly ["x", "y", "z"]' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.
}

const myTest: MyInteface = {
    name: `x`
}
```

I think it's possible. Does anyone have an Idea?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you're trying to use `string` to index the `names` array. You don't use strings to index an array—you use numbers, right? Make that quick change and it should work as expected.

```
const names = [`x`, `y`, `z`] as const;

interface MyInteface {
    name: typeof names[number];
}

const myTest: MyInteface = {
    name: `x`
}
```